# How do I copy regex found strings from one file to another, maintaining the structure of both files?

Tags: python, regex, file, replace

I am looking for help here. I have two very similar files, but they have different numbers in some tags, so I want to find these numbers in file1, then copy them, each number one by one, to file2 in the same place. (the scructure of both files is the same - except these id numbers)

What I wish to achieve in short:

1. Search for strings in File1 using Regex
2. Search for strings in File2 using the same Regex
3. Go through matches in File1, one by one, in order to replace each found match from File2 for the each found match in File1, one by one.

So if file1 has multiple strings like this: id23523_324 (but each string has different number) and file2 also has different similar strings, then I want to have those id numbers in file2 to be replaced by those in file1.

The below code isn't working.

````py
import re

file1 = r'C:\Users\file1.txt'
file2 = r'C:\Users\file2.txt'
pattern = re.compile(r'id\d\d\d\d\_\d\d\d')

with open(file2) as f1 : 
  content = f1.readlines() 
  content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

with open(file1) as f2 : 
  content2 = f2.readlines() 
  content2 = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for line in content : 
  for line2 in content2 : 
      re.sub(pattern,pattern,line)

with open(file1, 'w') as f2:
    for line in content2 : 
      f2.write(line+'\n')```

#I expect the file2.txt to have the same id numbers as in file1.txt.
````

Comment: Is there only ever one ID in either file or do you want to replace the 1st match in F2 by 1st match in F1, 2nd match in F2 buy 2nd match in F2 etc?

Comment: All the IDs are unique both in F1 and F2. I would like to replace 1st match in F2 by 1st match in F1, 2nd match in F2 by 2nd match in F1, etc. Yes.

Comment: Are you able to help here, Patrick?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we might want to have an exact match on some IDs in files. Your original expression seems to be fine, might be just missing one digit, and this expression might work:

```
(id[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{3})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/EJ8VzS/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(id[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{3})"

test_str = "id23523_324"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Thank you Emma for trying to help me here. All the IDs are unique both in F1 and F2. I would like to replace 1st match in F2 by 1st match in F1, 2nd match in F2 by 2nd match in F1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: 
- 1 id per line
- same number of ids -if not zip will work until the lower amount of IDs, rest is unchanged

You can modify the code if 1 id/line does not hold: see @ end.

**Create demo data:**

```
file1 = r'.\file1.txt'
file2 = r'.\file2.txt'

with open(file1,"w") as f:
    f.write("trivia\n")
    for k in range(1000,1003):
        for i in range(200,202):
            f.write(f"some text id{k}_{i} some more text\n ")
    f.write("trivia\n")
    f.write("trivia\n")

with open(file2,"w") as f:
    for k in range(4000,4003):
        f.write("trivia\n")
        for i in range(700,702): 
            f.write(f"llll id{k}_{i} fffff\n")
```

**Process files:**

Replaces any n-th id in *file1* by the n-th id in *file2*:
- find all ids in file1 => list
- find all ids in file2 => list
- zip them to get tuples that tell you what to replace by what
- read file1 again, create output file
- for each line of file 1:
 - replace i-st thing from zipped hits if it is in line 
 - advance index i
 - write line to results
- else copy line verbatim to results

Code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'id\d{4}_\d{3}')

with open(file1) as f : 
    f1 = pattern.findall(f.read())

with open(file2) as f : 
    f2 = pattern.findall(f.read())

change = list(zip(f1,f2))

with open("result.txt", 'w') as f, open(file1) as r:
    i = 0
    lc = len(change)
    for line in r:
        if i < lc and change[i][0] in line:
            line = line.replace(change[i][0],change[i][1])
            i += 1
        f.write(line)

print("# FILE1:\n", open(file1).read())
print("# FILE2:\n", open(file2).read())
print("# RESULT:\n", open("result.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
# FILE1:
 trivia
some text id1000_200 some more text
 some text id1000_201 some more text
 some text id1001_200 some more text
 some text id1001_201 some more text
 some text id1002_200 some more text
 some text id1002_201 some more text
 trivia
trivia

# FILE2:
 trivia
llll id4000_700 fffff
llll id4000_701 fffff
trivia
llll id4001_700 fffff
llll id4001_701 fffff
trivia
llll id4002_700 fffff
llll id4002_701 fffff

# RESULT:
 trivia
some text id4000_700 some more text
 some text id4000_701 some more text
 some text id4001_700 some more text
 some text id4001_701 some more text
 some text id4002_700 some more text
 some text id4002_701 some more text
 trivia
trivia
```

Iterating through the tuples by idx `i` is a optimization. With multiple IDs per line you can do:

```
    for line in r:
        for old_id, new_id in change:
            line = line.replace(old_id,new_id)
        f.write(line)
```

But that is slower because each line checks for all possible id matches.

Comment: This is wonderful, Patrick. Thank you for this. Demo works great, but the next code outputs me such an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KK\r.py", line 20, in <module>
    if i < lc and change[i][0] in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Comment: @robb - check your code, you seem to do something different with `change` - it seems to contain on more level of nesting. `print` it and inspect it it should look like a list of tuples and the tuple-elements are differents IDs.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this: `for line in r: for old_id, new_id in change: line = line.replace(old_id,new_id) f.write(line)` ...to actually copy 1st match in FILE1 to the 1st and 2nd match in FILE2? 1st and 2nd matches in FILE2 are the same, they are doubled (in general - each match in FILE2 is doubled - has the same result/strings), that's why I'd need to do it like this. Then 2nd match from FILE1 to be copied onto 3rd and 4th match in FILE2, 3rd match in F1 to 5th and 6th match in F2, etc. Is it possible? How should I modify the code to achieve it? I'd appreciate any help on this.